# Can I use regular expression to match two a characters only one time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

Can I split string by regex to match two parameters (: , ) only one time?

```
let str='part1:20/02/2002 part3 part4 part5';
let splittedArr=str.split(something..);
```

I would like the splittedArr to look like:
[part1 , 20/02/2002 , part3 part4 part5]

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far? Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in js you can split on a regex

and the regex is fairly simple its ":" or " "

the or in regex is a |

```js
let str='part1:20/02/2002 part3 part4 part5';
let splittedArr=str.split(/:| /);

console.log(splittedArr);
```

## **EDIT**

I've misinterpreted the question, if I understand your question correctly;
You want to split on the first colon (:) and on the first space ( ), and capture those 3 parts.

You can achieve this with simple group matches, and ungreedy wildcards.

```js
    let str='part1:20/02/2002 part3 part4 part5';
    
    let parts=str.match('^(.*?):(.*?) (.*)$');
    
    console.log(parts);
```

Comment: I know but I was wondering if I could split it into 3 parts only :
[0] = part1
[1]=the date
[3]= part3 part4 part5

Comment: thank you that is exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: normally you don't posts comments like thanks, etc, and don't forget to accept a post that solves your problem.